# Log4j:Logs are displying on console but File is not getting updated

Tags: log4j

Here i am using log4j API in standalone application in Netbeans.Logs are getting printed on console but NOT in File.Log4j file is present in the source folder .Please help me!
Below is the my log4j.properties file

```
log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.file.layout.ConversionPattern=%d %5p %c{1}\:%L - %m%n
log4j.appender.file.File=E:\\Final\\Testing123.log
log4j.appender.file.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.file.DatePattern`enter code here`='.'yyyy-MM-dd
log4j.logger.testing=DEBUG, stdout, file
log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=%d %5p %c{1}\:%L - %m%n
log4j.appender.file=org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.stdout.Target=System.out
```

and below is the class where i am using it.

```
public class Test {
     protected static  Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(Testing.class.getName());   

     public static void main(String[] args) {

         logger.debug("Test Log1");
         Test t = new Test();
         logger.debug("Test Log2");
         //t.setLogPropertyFile();
         logger.debug("Test Log3");
         t.testthis();
         logger.debug("Test Log4");
    }

    public void testthis(){
         this.logger.debug("Test Log");
         this.logger.info("Test Log");
         this.logger.warn("Test Log");
         this.logger.error("Test Log");
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like your problem is here:

```
log4j.appender.file.DatePattern`enter code here`='.'yyyy-MM-dd
```

Probably a copy/paste thing, but it should look like this:

```
log4j.appender.file.DatePattern='.'yyyy-MM-dd
```

Also, its a lot easier to see what is going on if you organize the config file:

```
log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.stdout.Target=System.out
log4j.appender.stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=%d %5p %c{1}\:%L - %m%n

log4j.appender.file=org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.file.File=E:\\Final\\Testing123.log
log4j.appender.file.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.file.layout.ConversionPattern=%d %5p %c{1}\:%L - %m%n
log4j.appender.file.DatePattern='.'yyyy-MM-dd

log4j.logger.testing=DEBUG, stdout, file
```

**---- Edit ----**

If running as a standalone java application, you will need to Configure your log4j framework at startup.  You can find information about this in the *Configuration* section of [the documentation](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/manual.html).  Specifically, since you are trying to use a properties file, you will need to do something like this (*borrowed directly from the documentation*):

```
 import com.foo.Bar;

 import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
 import org.apache.log4j.PropertyConfigurator;

 public class MyApp {

   static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(MyApp.class.getName());

   public static void main(String[] args) {


     // BasicConfigurator replaced with PropertyConfigurator.
     PropertyConfigurator.configure(args[0]);

     logger.info("Entering application.");
     Bar bar = new Bar();
     bar.doIt();
     logger.info("Exiting application.");
   }
 }
```

Comment: Hi, i tried it by replacing old one with this..but still its not working.Here log file is getting created but nothis is getting write into it..its blank :-(

Comment: Are you sure your log4j is getting initialized from your properties file?  You could be seeing default logging going to stdout.  Try changing your logger to: `log4j.logger.testing=ERROR, stdout, file` and make sure only error messages get logged...

Comment: i tried above its not working...all message are getting printed..below is the output m getting after changing logger to ERROR:  20:49:26.362 [main] DEBUG testing.Testing - Test Log1
20:49:26.378 [main] DEBUG testing.Testing - Test Log2
20:49:26.378 [main] DEBUG testing.Testing - Test Log3
20:49:26.378 [main] DEBUG testing.Testing - Test Log
20:49:26.378 [main] INFO  testing.Testing - Test Log
20:49:26.378 [main] WARN  testing.Testing - Test Log
20:49:26.378 [main] ERROR testing.Testing - Test Log
20:49:26.378 [main] DEBUG testing.Testing - Test Log4

Comment: So, since you are getting DEBUG messages still, you can infer that your log4j is not getting initialized from your properties file.  What infrastructure are you using?  Is this a web app?  What servlet container?  What other frameworks?  They all initialize logging slightly differently.

Comment: no...its simple java program...its standalone...no framework nothing..actually it is working properly for my other application.but when i tried it for new one,its giving this problem

Comment: If standalone, then you are either not initializing the logging framework correctly, or it is finding some other config file.

Comment: But then how will initialize it ? do we need to do something more than this to initialize? how will fix this? please help as its become critical issue for me.I am struggling for this from last 2 days:-(